# Why Django CheckConstraint doesn't works on MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

When I create one class with constraint like below:

```
constraints = [
    models.CheckConstraint(
            check=models.Q('plan' == 1),
            name="custom_constraint"
        )
]
```

I receive the message:

```
(models.W027) MySQL does not support check constraints.
        HINT: A constraint won't be created. Silence this warning if you don't care about it.
```

Why Django CheckConstraints works with PostgreSQL and not with MySQL?

Comment: MySQL ignores the CHECK constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html), the `CHECK` constraints are ignored by the MySQL database prior to 8.0.16:

> **Prior to MySQL 8.0.16**, `CREATE TABLE` permits only the following limited version of table **`CHECK`** constraint syntax, which is parsed
> and ignored**:
>
> ```
> CHECK (expr)
> ```
>
> **As of MySQL 8.0.16**, `CREATE TABLE` permits the **core features of table and column `CHECK` constraints**, for all storage engines.
> `CREATE TABLE` permits the following `CHECK` constraint syntax, for
> both table constraints and column constraints:
>
> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] CHECK (expr) [[NOT] ENFORCED]
> ```

So before 8.0.16, the `CHECK` constraint was indeed parsed, but the database engine ignored it, and thus data could violate the constraints.

Some specific constraints like `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE`, and `FOREIGN KEY` are however enforced, but not generic constraints (like a column that should have a specific value).

Comment: Since MySQL does indeed enforce the check constraints (after 8.0.16) I find this answer a bit strange as it starts with "the check constraints are ignored by the MySQL database". Does it work or does it not, after 8.0.16 with Django? :)