# MySQL 8.0.27 not accepting django check constraints

Tags: mysql, django

I have seen a 2 years old [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631395/why-django-checkconstraint-doesnt-works-on-mysql) to this but the question did not specify the MySQL version and there is no answers to the question.

I'm use the django(2.2.28) [constraint API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) to create a model that has 2 foreign keys but both of them cannot exist together and both of them cannot be null at the same time. The constraints look something like this:

```
CheckConstraint(check=Q(type='campaign', campaign__isnull=False), name='check_campaign_data'),
CheckConstraint(check=Q(type='trigger', trigger__isnull=False), name='check_trigger_data'),
```

The type indicates which foreign key the model will be using.

However, the following warning appears on my console:

```
(models.W027) MySQL does not support check constraints.
HINT: A constraint won't be created. Silence this warning if you don't care about it.
```

I have seen that this is now supported for MySQL 8.0.16 or higher.

I logged into the MySQL database and ran the command

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.27    |
+-----------+
```

Why is this not working if this version of MySQL is supposed to support this feature?

Comment: `mysql --version` only tells you the version of the client. You should run the SQL query: `SELECT VERSION();` which tells you the version of the server. That's what determines if the server supports check constraints.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I ran the command and the version of the server is also 8.0.27. I will update the question

Comment: Which version of Django is it, and is there a mysql feature support version table in Django?

Comment: I think the Django developers have not understood that MySQL now supports check constraints. Look at the response on this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31409 The response seems to defer to the client-side simulation of check constraints, and does not acknowledge that MySQL now supports them in the database.

Comment: @DannyStaple I'm using django 2.2.28

Comment: @BillKarwin I see, do you think that the CheckConstraint would work even with  this warning? I have a very limited knowledge of SQL

Comment: It depends if Django has executed anything to create the constraint, or if it has skipped that because it thinks MySQL doesn't support the constraint. I would double-check by opening the database with the `mysql` client, and use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` to see if the check constraint was in fact created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what Bill karwin suggested and saw that the Check Constraint is in fact created and works as expected even with the warning.
To ignore the warning I just added the following to my settings.py:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ["models.W027"]
```